# I have three functions that take the same object as a parameter. But the latter two don't do anything

Tags: kotlin

I have a class "Sample", which holds data. I want to pad this data left, right and centered. I don't post the code for Sample, because I am pretty sure, that's not where the problem is situated. (If it's needed, I will.) The following code shows how I proceed.

```
val hline_magf = SampleUtils.getDataFromOneFile("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Desktop\\test\\hline.421.magf.csv")
val adj_ts = Preprocess.adjustTimestamps(hline_magf)
val abs = Preprocess.abs(adj_ts)
var lerp = Preprocess.lerp(abs)
val lh = Preprocess.hanning_window(lerp)

val lhl = Preprocess.pad_left(lh)           // these cause the problems somewhere
val lhr = Preprocess.pad_right(lh)
val lhm = Preprocess.pad_center(lh)
```

The first steps shape the data, and work well. (The preprocess-functions all take Sample-objects and return Sample-objects.) But as soon as I use either of the pad-functions the other pad-functions don't work anymore.

If I pad left at first lhr and lhm are also padded left, if I pad right at first the others are padded right as well.

The pad functions work as intended when put first, I tested the three variations.

This is how the functions look:

```
    fun pad_left(sample: Sample): Sample {
        var ret_val = sample
        println("#### pad left")

        while (ret_val.timestamp.size < MAX_LEN) ret_val.timestamp = doubleArrayOf(0.0) + ret_val.timestamp
        while (ret_val.absoluteSquare_float.size < MAX_LEN) ret_val.absoluteSquare_float = floatArrayOf(0.0f) + ret_val.absoluteSquare_float
        while (ret_val.x_float.size < MAX_LEN) ret_val.x_float = floatArrayOf(0.0f) + ret_val.x_float
        while (ret_val.y_float.size < MAX_LEN) ret_val.y_float = floatArrayOf(0.0f) + ret_val.y_float
        while (ret_val.z_float.size < MAX_LEN) ret_val.z_float = floatArrayOf(0.0f) + ret_val.z_float

        return ret_val
    }
```

EDIT:
Thanks to yole. I've added a copy()-method to my class, which returns a new object.

Comment: Each of your functions mutates the original sample and returns it. Because of that, after the three pad calls, all the objects will be identical. You need to create a copy of the object.

Comment: I thought I do this by var ret_val = sample

Comment: This does not create a copy of the object, it creates another reference pointing to the same object.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this? I don't see the difference right now.

Comment: If `Sample` is a data class, you can use the `copy()` method. Otherwise, you need to write your own code to create a new `Sample` instance and initialize it with values from your previous instance.

Comment: It's not a data class. Thanks a lot.